# In Python,how can I add to a dictionare from raw_input,for both key and value? M

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
students = {}
name = input("Give me the student name(key): ")
grade = input("What is their Grade(value): ")
```

'(put in to dictionary key=name and value = grade
print all students and their grades from dictionary"

Comment: i'm not able to add to dictionary from input. can you give me a little example of adding key and value from input?

Comment: Why don't you Google search for how to use dictionaries? As it is, your question is very unclear.

Comment: @Lavo just try `student.update({ name : grade})` as there may be an issue resolving the key (name).

Answer (score 0):

```
students = {}
name = input("Give me the student name(key): ")
grade = input("What is their Grade(value): ")
students[name] = grade
```

You can just use `students[key] = value`

Comment: `students[name] = grade` could have been added as a comment. Fixing the basics of the OP's understanding here neither helps them to learn how to research their problem, nor benefits other people.

Comment: That is what I did before. retried. I get  msg 'name' not  defined after I enter the student name. I know name would be the key and the grade would be the value. and looping around should let me add another entry. but I can get the first entry in? I tried you example to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should do your job. For details on how to add to dictionary you can refer the links shared above or go through the python documentation for it.

```
students = {}
name = input("Give me the student name(key): ")
grade = input("What is their Grade(value): ")
students[name] = grade
print(students)
```

Comment: that's also how I tried it. I also, ran your code too mayurmadnani. I defined my dictionary students ={}. Am I missing a definition other than the code you listed. of course im running on python 2.7. I can pre fill my dictionary by hard coding it ,but not by input.

Comment: what challenge are you facing? the above snippet works. See the output below

Comment: Give me the student name(key): me
    What is their Grade(value): 2
    {'me': '2'}

Comment: I  found the problem. it needs quotes when you type in the key at a input prompt... i.e 'student1'. but how will I get the quotes around the input field . Maybe I can format it